# Setting global styles with multiple parameters for tikz calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I'd like to create a style with parameters for use with the TikZ `calendar` library.

Here's a working example similar to what I want:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{ColorDay}=[if={(equals=2-7) [every day/.append style=#1]}]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar (cal) [dates=2013-02-1 to 2013-02-28,week list,
    ColorDay={red}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have two problems.

First, I am forced to use the deprecated `\tikzstyle` command here, instead of `\tikzset`. I can't get `\tikzset` to work at all with `calendar` if's. For instance,

```
\tikzset{ColorDay/.style=if={(equals=2-7) [every day/.append style=#1]}}
```

doesn't work. In fact, it doesn't work even if I remove the parameter.

```
\tikzset{ColorDay/.style=if={(equals=2-7) [every day/.append style=red]}}
```

Second, I don't know how to create a style with multiple parameters. For instance,

```
\tikzstyle{ColorDay}=[if={(equals=#1) [every day/.append style=#2]}]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

`\tikzset` does work here, but you need to use a set of braces if the style contains commas or equal signs. To get a style with two arguments, use `\tikzset{Color Day/.style 2 args={...}}`, or if you want even more arguments, use `\tikzset{Color Day/.style n args={3}{...}}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    ColorDay/.style 2 args={
        if={(equals=#1) [every day/.append style=#2]}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar (cal) [dates=2013-02-1 to 2013-02-28,week list,
    ColorDay={2-7}{red},
    ColorDay={2-16}{blue, font=\bfseries}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user31463: That's great! In that case, you can upvote and accept the answer by clicking the upward pointing triangle and the tick mark next to it. That will close the question.