# Arguments for TikZ style

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

## Motivation

To put arrows inside of a TikZ path I have defined myself a TikZ style `arrow inside`. To make it even more portable I want it to take arguments like this

```
\draw[arrow inside={pos = 0.1, end = |}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
```

such that I can define the position of the arrow using `pos` and the type of the arrow by `end`. **If no arguments are given it should fall back to the defaults.**

> [image]

## What I have tried so far

To achive the above picture, I wrote the following snippet. The problem is that the values are properly stored in the macros I defined, but are not being updated, nor do I now, how to retain the defaults.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    arrow inside/pos/.store in = \arrow@inside@pos,
    arrow inside/end/.store in = \arrow@inside@end,
    arrow inside/pos = 0.5,
    arrow inside/end = >,
    arrow inside/.style = {
        postaction = {
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position \arrow@inside@pos with {\arrow{\arrow@inside@end}}
            }
        }
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[arrow inside={pos = 0.1, end = |}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]
\end{document}
```

---

Possibly related:

- [Arguments of tikzset inside a beamer document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119309/arguments-of-tikzset-inside-a-beamer-document)
- [Setting global styles with multiple parameters for tikz calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116736/setting-global-styles-with-multiple-parameters-for-tikz-calendar/116738#116738)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake) is correct in his [now deleted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131321/16595). The options you pass to `arrow inside` are not applied as they are simply grabbed and not used (i.e. “gobbled”) similar to `#1` in:

```
\newcommand*{\myCommand}[1]{Foobar Rhubarb}% no "#1" in its definition
```

You need to add `#1` in your `.style` definition.

But instead of using the `.store in` handler, consider using `.initial` keys which simply store a value. This way, you don’t add another layer of abstraction (PGFkeys already use a specific “namespace”), no need to add your own `\arrow@inside@…` macros if PGFkeys already uses `/tikz/arrow inside/…`.

To also avoid troubles with `/.cd` inside a `.style`, I’d use a specific key `set arrow inside` that sets the path to `/tikz/arrow inside`.

#### References

- [What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129577/16595)
- [When to use a regular .initial key or a .store in key?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125197/16595)
- [Key that takes a list of other keys as argument and sets them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125676/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
  set arrow inside={pos/.initial=.5, end/.initial=>},
  arrow inside/.style={
    set arrow inside={#1},
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/pos}
             with \arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
      }
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[arrow inside={pos = 0.1, end = |}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### But why stop there?

Sometimes users want to use more than one arrow tip along a (part of a) path which I realized [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130987/a-simple-indented-integration-contour-with-tikz/130995#comment295496_130995) should be made better.

The following solution doesn’t use a `pos` key anymore (this can be changed) but applies the options `end` and `opt` to a list of arrow-tip marks in a decoration.

(Note that for regular intervals, the library also provides `mark=between positions <start> and <end> step <step> with <marking>`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
  set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
  /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
    mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
    {\noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}}},
  arrow inside/.style 2 args={
    set arrow inside={#1},
    postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,Mark/.list={#2}}}},
}
\begin{document}
\tikz[thick]
  \draw[
    arrow inside={
      end=|,
      opt=red!\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}0!blue
    }{0, .05, .15, .3, .5, .7, .85, .95, 1},
  ] (0,0) to[bend left] (4,0);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer! I will reward it with a small bounty as soon as it's possible, because of the extra credit with the sequence of markings inside. (BTW: Where did Jake's answer go?)

Comment: @HenriMenke: I deleted mine, because it doesn't add anything that Qrrbrbirlbel's doesn't cover.

Comment: Also: [TikZ: Can a \foreach command run inside decoration = {markings,?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126414)

Answer (score 18):

I suggest a different approach, not optimal (see [What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/what-do-the-pgfkeys-key-handlers-get-and-store-in-do)), but it works. Indeed, one problem in your code is that, inside `arrow style` the keys do not inherit the correct path `/tikz/arrow inside/key-name`. To make it working you can do something like:

```
\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[/tikz/arrow inside/pos = 0.4,/tikz/arrow inside/end = |,arrow inside] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]
```

which is not so convenient IMHO. The other problem is that if you define a style doing something with keys, those keys have to be set not inside the style, but before as I did with the above code. Notice that:

```
\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[arrow inside={/tikz/arrow inside/pos = 0.4,/tikz/arrow inside/end = |}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]
```

does not do anything as the keys still have the values `0.5` and `>` respectively.

So, my approach will be based on the "triple" handlers `initial`, `get` and `store in` and will let you use:

```
arrow inside={pos = 0.4,end = |}
```

inside `\draw`.

First I would define the keys:

```
\pgfkeys{/arrow inside/.cd,
  pos/.initial  = 0.5,
  pos/.get      = \arrow@inside@pos,
  pos/.store in = \arrow@inside@pos,
  end/.initial  = >,
  end/.get      = \arrow@inside@end,
  end/.store in = \arrow@inside@end,
}
```

They are under the path `/arrow inside/` so later on we should take care of this.

Second, I would define a style to place the arrow:

```
place arrow/.style = {
    postaction = {
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position \arrow@inside@pos with {\arrow{\arrow@inside@end}}
        }
    }
},
```

Rather than the keys, the style belongs to the usual `/tikz/` path. To combine the keys and the aforementioned style, I define:

```
arrow inside/.style={place arrow,/arrow inside/.cd,#1}
```

as a style which "places" the arrow and, by changing the default `/tikz/` path, allows you to use the previously defined keys.

A mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/arrow inside/.cd,
  pos/.initial  = 0.5,
  pos/.get      = \arrow@inside@pos,
  pos/.store in = \arrow@inside@pos,
  end/.initial  = >,
  end/.get      = \arrow@inside@end,
  end/.store in = \arrow@inside@end,
}
\tikzset{arrow inside/.style={place arrow,/arrow inside/.cd,#1},
    place arrow/.style = {
        postaction = {
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position \arrow@inside@pos with {\arrow{\arrow@inside@end}}
            }
        }
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[arrow inside={pos = 0.4,end = |}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]


\[ \int_{
    \tikz[scale=0.3]{
        \path[fill=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (1.5,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
        \draw[arrow inside={pos = 0.7,end = stealth}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
    }
} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{n} \, df \]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Notice that the keys now update correctly their values.

Comment: I think the best explanation for this has been given by percusse in [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/what-do-the-pgfkeys-key-handlers-get-and-store-in-do#comment292183_129707). Indeed, as also my answer there demonstrates, the `.get` handler is needed for, let's say, the special case in which you first use the keys without passing any values (the `initial` ones are given) and then you use them with values. In this case, try to say `\draw[arrow inside={}] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);` in the first example: the compilation will rise errors as both macros won't be defined.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. If I could I would accept both, but I will reward yours with a small bounty as soon as it's possible for giving a great insight on `.get` and `.store in`.