# TikZ circuits : how to define aliases

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I am typing an awful lot of electrical circuits, and when I used LaTeX I used the circuitikz library, which has a simple and concise syntax. Now that I switched to ConTeXt, I have to use the TikZ circuit, which is almost perfect in terms of capabilities, but is also a lot more verbose.

I would like to define aliases (like `R` for `resistor`, `l` for label, `V` for a voltage arrow and so on). I found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155803/is-it-possible-to-define-abbreviations-for-coding), as well as this example in the TikZ manual:

```
\tikzset{r/.style={radius=#1},rx/.style={x radius=#1},ry/.style={y radius=#1}}
```

My first problem is that I can't find how to make subkeys work as well ; I don't know how to clearly explain it, so here is a MWE that describes the problem :

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[circuits.ee.IEC]
\tikzset{
  R/.style={resistor},
  l/.style={info}
}

\starttext
Basic usage \blank
\starttikzpicture[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [resistor={near start}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (3,0) to [resistor={info=$a$}] ++(2,0);
\stoptikzpicture

\hairline
My tests
\blank
\starttikzpicture[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [R={near start}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (3,0) to [R={info=$a$}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (6,0) to [R={l=$a$}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (9,0) to [R] ++(2,0);
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]

As soon as I use my abbreviation, all the keys I can specify as optional are not read, whether I use my abbreviation `l` for the option or not.

My second problem is that I tried to define a voltage arrow that suits me, and I found the `circuit declare annotation` key in the pgf manual, with the following example :

```
\tikzset{circuit declare annotation=
  {circular annotation}
  {9pt}
  {(0pt,8pt) arc (-270:80:3.5pt)}
}
```

However, I can't find how to make an arrow which size is linked to the node's size ; I tried using `(north east) -- (north west)`, but it appeared to me that there is no node name here, and should write something like `(this node.north west)`... Is there a way to specify something as "this node" ?

Comment: For your first issue instead of  `R/.style={resistor},  l/.style={info}` try with `R/.style={resistor={#1}},
  l/.style={info={#1}}`

Comment: This works perfectly. I tried without the braces around the #1, I don't know why I didn't use the braces. If you could write an answer with a bit of explanation, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy style with one argument to another you can use this  method

```
Newstyle/.style={Oldstyle={#1}}
```

Here braces `{#1}` are added  to create group which includes `Oldstyle` key list

**Code**

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[circuits.ee.IEC]
\tikzset{
  R/.style={resistor={#1}},
  l/.style={info={#1}}
}

\starttext
Basic usage \blank
\starttikzpicture[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [resistor={near start}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (3,0) to [resistor={info=$a$}] ++(2,0);
\stoptikzpicture

\hairline
My tests
\blank
\starttikzpicture[circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0) to [R={near start}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (3,0) to [R={info=$a$}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (6,0) to [R={l=$a$}] ++(2,0);
  \draw (9,0) to [R] ++(2,0);
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]