# Expanding arguments to pgf/tikz styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, pgfkeys

In an answer on this site is proposed [a method to draw arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131325/3968) on paths. For example, using the style `[arrow inside={pos=0.2}]` will put an arrow at position `0.2` on the path :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
  set arrow inside={pos/.initial=.5, end/.initial=>},
  arrow inside/.style={
    set arrow inside={#1},
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/pos} with \arrow{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
      }
    }
  },
}

\draw[arrow inside={pos=0.2}] (0,0) -- (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, I would like to do something like

```
\draw[arrow inside={pos=0.2}, arrow inside={pos=0.8}] (0,0) -- (5cm,5cm);
```

and end up with two arrows, one at position 0.2 and the other at position 0.8. This does not work, because the second call to `set arrow inside` modifies the value of the key `/tikz/arrow inside/pos` and hence the style (only the second arrow is drawn). I tried to play with expansion rules, but I fail to wrap my mind around these things, so I hope perhaps somebody else will manage to do so (or perhaps the problem is somewhere else, and then I hope somebody will point out where !).

For the record, [the original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131325/3968) also provides another way to circumvent this problem by modifying the syntax a little, and that solution may be useful in practice. (However, I for one am interested in a solution to the evaluation order problem.) Thanks in advance !

Comment: Last setting always win. So, IMHO is not that easy to keep the same syntax as you're going to exploit the same keys several times.

Comment: Yes, it is tricky. What I believe I need to do is to first parse the pgfkeys arguments to set the relevant macros (or pgf keys values), and then to produce an _expanded_ style and to use it. Then, the contents of the macros/keys can change without affecting the style (because they were expanded). However, I don't know how to do that, hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  arrowmark/.style 2 args={postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrowmark={.2}{<},arrowmark={.8}{>}] (0,0) -- (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, no. I want to keep the syntax `arrow inside={pos=0.2}` and to be able to use several of them. I know there are several other options ! However, I am interested in this specific problem :) Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Few years later ... you can use a nested macros for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  arrow inside/.style={
    decoration={markings},
    end/.style={
      pos/.style={
        decoration={
          mark=at position ####1 with {\expandafter\arrow##1}
        }
      }
    },
    end=>,
    #1,
    postaction={decorate}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[arrow inside={pos=0.2},arrow inside={end={[red,scale=3]{latex}},pos=0.7}] (0,0) -- (5cm,5cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]